# Как быстро скачивать большие обьемы данных с сервера

Tags: ftp

Пробывал filezilla и lftp нужно что-то быстрее. Скачивать 200 мб 3 часа не очень хочется

Comment: Всё зависит от скорости сервера, скорости клиента, числа и размера отдельных файлов (а не суммы их размеров), производительности носителей, фрагментации файлов на сервере и нагрузки на него

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Архивировать в zip. И можно скачать его через http протокол(не безопасно), если ftp работает медленно. Возможно вся проблема, не в размере,а в количестве файлов, можно попытаться сначала упаковать в zip, а потом скачать через фтп.